# Counting the number of solutions produced by N Queens function.

Tags: python, list, count

I have written a function that produces all the possible solutions for the N queens problem. It takes an integer input from the user which is the dimensions of the table. I.e if the user enters 4 then it will list all possible solutions for a 4x4 table. The output looks like this when n=4 is the input:

```
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
```

This is the function I used:

```
def nQueens(partialSolution, n):
    allPositions = getPositions(partialSolution, n)
    if len(partialSolution) == n:
        print(partialSolution)
    else:
        for item in allPositions: 
            partialSolution.append(item)
            nQueens(partialSolution, n)
            partialSolution.pop()
nQueens([], n)
```

Somewhere in this function I need to implement a count variable that at the end will output the number of solutions. For example, if 4 is entered then it will output 2 because there are two solutions:

```
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
2
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
count = 0
for i in partialSolution:
    count+=1
print(count)
```

Because it is not within the function itself, I get an error saying that partialSolution is not defined. I'm not sure how to implement something like this into the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct, you could try to return the count on the function, the base case would be when it actually prints a solution, like this (be careful, untested code):

```
def nQueens(partialSolution, n):
    allPositions = getPositions(partialSolution, n)
    if len(partialSolution) == n:
        print(partialSolution)
        return 1
    else:
        ctr = 0
        for item in allPositions: 
            partialSolution.append(item)
            ctr += nQueens(partialSolution, n)
            partialSolution.pop()

        return ctr
```

The base case returns one, because it prints a valid solution, then, after doing the recursive call, you sum the number of solutions found so far before going to the next branch of the recursion.

Comment: This did not work, it only produced the lists of possible solutions.

Comment: Are you printing the returned value?, it should be something like this: print(nQueens([], n))

Comment: At the end I'm just calling the funcftion: nQueens([]. n)

Comment: My apologies, your code did actually work once you do print(nQueens([], n)). Thank you for your help!